# TFS 2015 Build vNext: Upload Files via WebDAV?

Tags: webdav, tfs-2015

We want to upload files to a WebDAV-Folder and tried to use the "**Windows Machine File Copy**"-task for that (this uses ROBOCOPY inside). But we don´t see any possibility to enter the destination folder in the right form.
1. We tried

```
\\our.website.de@SSL\DavWWWRoot\remote.php\webdav\
```

and 
2. we also mounted this location as a network drive first and tried to use the drive letter,
but none of these attempts succeeded.

Is "Windows Machine File Copy" the right type of task for that or is there any custom task out there that accomplishes what we need?
Thx...

Answer (score 0):

You should separate specified Machines and the folder path. Do not use it together.

> **Machines:**
>
> Example: `dbserver.fabrikam.com, dbserver_int.fabrikam.com:5986,192.168.34:5986`
>
> **Folder Path:**
>
> The folder on the Windows machine(s) to which the files will be
>   copied.
>
> Example: `C:\FabrikamFibre\Web`

More detail info please refer this link: [Deploy: Windows Machine File Copy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy)